# How to describe a person who wakes up agitated because he thinks he is too late to finish certain job on time?

Tags: word-choice

What is a good word or phrase that I can use to describe a person who wakes up agitated because he thinks that he is too late to finish certain job on time?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please [clarify your specific problem](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean *How do you describe a person who wakes up agitated because he thinks he is too late to finish a certain job on time.*?

Comment: What does "late to a late to ficish" mean. Please clarify your question.

Comment: I take it you mean "How would you describe a person who wakes up agitated because he thinks he is late to finish a certain job on time?"

Answer (score 1):

To wake up in a [*cold sweat*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cold-sweat), perhaps?

> **cold sweat** noun [ C ]
>
> a state of extreme worry and fear:
>
> - I break out in a cold sweat just thinking about public speaking.

Cambridge Dictionary

---

I sometimes have a nightmare where I have to go back to university to finish my degree. I definitely wake up in a cold sweat, and it can take me a few seconds to convince myself that it was just a bad dream.

Answer (score -1):

From a native speaker:

Use **time stressed and sleep deprived** to mean a feeling of pressure due to time and short on rest due to not enough sleep.  Time stress could come from running late and feeling agitated with rushing or worry. That agitation could in turn cause a bad night of sleep and waking up without feeling rested.